# How do I change the background of a checked ui:inputcheckbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, ui, checkbox

I am trying to set the background of my checked checkbox. This is the code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-checkbox">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="marketing" class="slds-input" value="{!v.identityRequest.Marketing__c}" change="{!c.onChange}" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding this to the styling makes the checkboxes black when they are not selected.

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox--faux{
background: black;
}
```

I would expect that this would work for the checked checkboxes:

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox--faux:checked{
background: black;
}
```

But is doesnt. This works for when it is active, but thats the state between checked and unchecked:

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox .slds-checkbox--faux:active{
background: black;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to set the background of my checked checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is to add a class on the parent container `slds-checkbox` if the value of the checkbox is set to `true` like this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__row">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="{!'slds-checkbox' + (v.identityRequest.Marketing__c ? ' checkbox-checked' : '')}">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="marketing" class="slds-input" value="{!v.identityRequest.Marketing__c}" change="{!c.onChange}" />
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add a class to your css:

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox.checkbox-checked .slds-checkbox--faux{
    background: black;
}
```